# multiple ip and subnets in virtual routed xen environment

Tags: networking, debian, virtualization, ip, routing

I'm trying to setup a multi ip, multi subnet environment using xen on debian wheezy host.
I have only one NIC and the guests are also debian wheezy.

this is my original, working, /etc/network/interfaces on dom0

```
# physical server IP
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address a.b.197.140
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway a.b.197.1

# Aliases all working when setup like this in dom0
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
  address a.b.197.141
  netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
  address a.b.197.139
  netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:3
iface eth0:3 inet static
  address a.b.193.149    #new subnet
  netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:4
iface eth0:4 inet static
  address a.b.192.23     #new subnet
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I've changed dom0 interface config to a routed (not bridged I think?) setup as follows.

```
# Main interface - working
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address a.b.197.140
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway a.b.197.1

# second interface - working in a.b.192.* on domU
auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet static
  bridge_ports none
  address a.b.192.254    #no address provided by ISP - its made up by me for gateway in domU
  netmask 255.255.255.0

# third interface - working in a.b.193.* on domU
auto xenbr1
iface xenbr1 inet static
  bridge_ports none
  address a.b.193.254    #no address provided by ISP - its made up by me for gateway in domU
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I've enabled packet forwarding and ARP in xen config file.

My domUs are:
domA, domB and domC

I want to assign addresses as follows.
I've found out there are some limitations with this setup and I need help to solve this.

```
domA (a.b.197.141)
domB (a.b.193.149)
domC (a.b.197.139, a.b.192.23)
```

The only working above is domB with the following configs in /etc/xen/domB.cfg

```
vif = ['bridge=xenbr1, ip=a.b.193.149, mac=some mac']
```

/etc/network/interfaces (domB)

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address a.b.193.149
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway a.b.193.254   #made up by me in dom0
```

domA, which is supposed to have ip in same subnet as dom0, only works when I use normal bridging as they suggest here: http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Beginners_Guide#Setup_Linux_Bridge_for_guest_networking

I've tried every possible setup that I could think of including:

```
1) use same gateway as in dom0
2) set up own interface (xenbr2) with address a.b.197.254 and use as gateway
3) use dom0 eth0 address (a.b.197.140) as gateway
```

domC, which is supposed to have ip in multiple subnets, doesn't work in either setup (routed or bridged).

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks /M